# О двойной фамилии потомка. Пунктуация для старшего/младшего

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика, фамилии

> Его авторы утверждают, что за оппозиционным журналистом Владимиром
> Кара-Мурзой — младшим, который дважды оказывался в больнице с тяжелым
> отравлением, следили...

https://www.rbc.ru/politics/11/02/2021/602542d49a7947d83d38ff6d

Стоит ли «отодвигать» обозначение «младший» посредством тире, или коль скоро оно нередко присоединяется дефисом, не избегать повтора? *Кара-Мурза-младший*?

> ...генерал армии Петров и с ним Иван Иванович Папиков, подполковник
> Петров-младший. [Вацлав Михальский. Прощеное воскресенье // Октябрь,
> 2009]

А так поступают «*academic.ru* (цитата Изд."БЕЛЫЙ ГОРОД"(2013) и wikireading.ru (Пост Пегги):

> Ханс Хольбейн Младший работал под руководством отца Ханса Хольбейна
> Старшего в Люцерне.
>
> Марк Порций Катон (младший) 95—46 до н.э. государственный деятель, противник Цезаря.

*Кара-Мурза (Младший)*?

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что написание *Владимир Кара-Мурза — младший* является вполне возможным.

Ориентируемся на ПАС ([§ 154](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)):
В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.
2. В сочетаниях с приложением, если одна из частей в свою очередь является сочетанием с приложением и содержит дефис, напр.: *рассказ о студенте-медике — альпинисте; встреча с приятелем — шахматистом-любителем; у соседа — писателя-фантаста.* Ср. *студент-альпинист, сосед-писатель.*

Считаю, что лучше написать так: *Владимир Кара-Мурза (младший)* или *младший Кара-Мурза*.
Сравните: Александр Лазарев-младший; Александр Лазарев (младший); Семёнов-Тян-Шанский (младший).

*Кара-Мурза (**М**ладший)* — так писать неверно.
Слова "Старший" и "Младший" пишутся с заглавной буквы только в том случае, если **непосредственно входят** в имя собственное.
Известные исторические имена: Плиний Старший и Плиний Младший.

Answer (score 1):

> Стоит ли «отодвигать» обозначение «младший» посредством тире, или коль
> скоро оно нередко присоединяется дефисом, не избегать повтора?
> Кара-Мурза-младший?

Дефис здесь не подходит просто по той причине, что "младший" относится не к только к фамилии, но и к имени. Здесь, конечно, чувствуется влияние английской систему, но в русском-то своей не выработано. Какая-то аналогия есть с использованием в дореволюционной армии порядковых числительных для различения однофамильцев (Иванов 7-й), то там цифрами писалось, да и случай не тот.

Что же до выбора из трех других вариантов, то тут полный разнобой. Исторические имена принято писать через пробел и с заглавной (Плиний Младший), но здесь опять же немного другой случай, Младший становится как бы частью принятого условного имени.

Использование же вариантов со скобками для имен наших современников [Сергей Бодров (младший)] и пробелом [Сергей Бодров младший] никем, ничем и нигде, насколько мне известно, не регламентируется, в википедии, например, встречаются самые разнообразные варианты. Использование заглавных букв (Младший), однако, выглядит нежелательным, поскольку для современных имен это уточнение не стало частью имени.

Исходя из всего сказанного, возьму на себя смелость рекомендовать написание по образцу ***Плиний Младший*** - для исторических имен (где дополнение не стало частью имени), ***Сергей Бодров -- младший*** и ***Джорж Буш -- младший*** для имен с устоявшимся использованием и англоязычных персон и со скобками -  ***Артем Боровик (младший)*** - во всех случаях, когда подобное обозначение не требуется сложившейся системой и несет в себе лишь авторское пояснение: Артем Боровик был сыном Генриха Боровика и, строго говоря, его имя не требовало уточнение "младший", но так сложилось, что именно к нему такое уточнение стали часто применять.

Еще менее определенный случай представляет собой написание английских имен типа ***James Brown III***. Но тут, впрочем, можно обойтись прямой транслитерацией   - ***Джеймс Браун III***, хотя подобное несколько противоречит сложившейся системе использования римских цифр.